# Manipulating variables to produce a new dataset in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm a relatively new R user. I would really appreciate any help with my dataset please.

I have a dataset with 24 million rows. There are 3 variables in the dataset: patient name, pharmacy name, and count of medications picked up from the pharmacy at that visit.

Some patients appear in the dataset more than once (ie. they have picked up medications from different pharmacies at different time points).

The data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Tom", "Rob", "Tom", "Tom",  "Amy"), 
                 pharmacy = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), 
                 meds = c(3, 2, 5, 8, 2))
```

From this data I want to generate a new dataset, which has ONE pharmacy for each patient. This pharmacy needs to be the one where the patient has picked up the highest number of medications.

For example: for Tom his most frequent pharmacy is Pharmacy B because he has picked up 13 medications from there (5+8 meds). The dataset I would like to generate:

```
data.frame(name = c("Tom", "Rob",  "Amy"), 
           pharmacy = c("B", "B", "C"), 
           meds = c(13, 2, 2))
```

Can someone please help me with writing a code to do this?
I have tried various functions in R, such as `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `aggregate()` with no success. Any help would be genuinely appreciated.

Thank you very much

Alex

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, I think you're looking for something like this.

```
require(tidyverse)
#Sample data. I copied yours. 
df <- data.frame(name = c("Tom", "Rob", "Tom", "Tom",  "Amy"), 
                 pharmacy = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), 
                 meds = c(3, 2, 5, 8, 2))
```

## Edit. I changed the group_by(), summarise() and added filter.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name, pharmacy) %>%
  summarise(SumMeds = sum(meds, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(SumMeds == max(SumMeds))
```

Results:

```
  name  pharmacy SumMeds
  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>
1 Amy   C             2.
2 Rob   B             2.
3 Tom   B            13.
```

Comment: result is not the same as OP request.

Comment: Tom - B - 8 + 5 = 13. One needs to group by name AND pharmacy

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not reproducible. But here is one solution:

```
# create reproducible example of data 
dataset1 <- data.frame( 
name = c("Tom", "Rob", "Tom", "Tom", "Amy"), 
pharmacy = c("pharmacy_A", "pharmacy_B", "pharmacy_B", "pharmacy_B", "pharmacy_C"),  
meds_count = c(3, 2, 5, 8, 2))

library(dplyr) #load dplyr

dataset2 <- dataset1 %>% group_by(name, pharmacy) %>% # group by your grouping variables
                   summarise(meds_count = sum(meds_count)) %>% # sum no. of meds by your grouping variables
                   top_n(1, meds_count) %>% # filter for only the top 1 count
                   ungroup()
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
> dataset2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  pharmacy   meds_count
  <fct> <fct>           <dbl>
1 Amy   pharmacy_C       2.00
2 Rob   pharmacy_B       2.00
3 Tom   pharmacy_B      13.0
```

Comment: Thank you much for your response and your help. This worked! I really appreciate it

Comment: Happy to hear that. Consider accepting the answer. And note that your answer was already contained in your question, all you had to do was to translate it to `dplyr` verbs: group my data by one pharmacy for each patient; summarise the data by the group by summing up the number of meds; from the resulting data, pick just the top one result for each patient/pharmacy group.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in base R with `aggregate` twice followed by `merge`.
It seems to me a bit complicated to have to use `aggregate` twice. Maybe `dplyr` solutions run more quickly, especially with a dataset with 24 million rows.

```
agg <- aggregate(meds ~ name + pharmacy, df, FUN = function(x) sum(x))
agg2 <- aggregate(meds ~ name, agg, function(x) x[which.max(x)])
merge(agg, agg2)[c(1, 3, 2)]
#  name pharmacy meds
#1  Amy        C    2
#2  Rob        B    2
#3  Tom        B   13
```

**Data.**
This is the dataset in the question after the edit.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Tom", "Rob", "Tom", "Tom",  "Amy"), 
                 pharmacy = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), 
                 meds = c(3, 2, 5, 8, 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: you could use `"\\D"` as your regex.

Comment: result is not the same as OP request.

Comment: @AndreElrico Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Generating your dataset:

```
patient = c("Tom","Rob","Tom","Tom","Amy")
pharmacy = c("A","B","B","B","C")
meds = c(3,2,5,8,2)
df = data.frame(patient,pharmacy,meds)
```

df is your dataframe

```
library(dplyr)

df = df %>% group_by(patient,pharmacy) %>% 
summarize(meds =sum(meds)) %>% 
group_by(patient) %>% 
filter(meds == max(meds))
```

- Take your df, group by patient and pharmacy
- calculate total medicines bought by each patient from different pharmacies by taking the sum of medicines.
- Then group_by patient
- Finally filter for max.

Print the dataframe

`print(df)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following dataset:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~patient, ~pharmacy, ~medication,  
  "Tom", "Pharmacy A", "3 meds",
  "Rob", "Pharmacy B", "2 meds",
  "Tom", "Pharmacy B", "5 meds",
  "Tom", "Pharmacy B", "8 meds",
  "Amy", "Pharmacy C", "2 meds"
)
```

A tidyverse-friendly option could be:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(med_n = as.numeric(str_extract(medication, "[0-9]"))) %>%  # 1
  group_by(patient, pharmacy) %>%  # 2
  mutate(med_sum = sum(med_n)) %>%  # 3
  group_by(patient) %>%  # 4
  filter(med_sum == max(med_sum)) %>%  # 5
  select(patient, pharmacy, med_sum) %>%  # 6
  distinct() # 7
```

1. create a numeric variable as you can't add strings
2. among all patient / pharmacy couples
3. find the total number of medications
4. then among all patients
5. keep only pharmacies with the highest patient / pharm totals
6. discard useless variables
7. discard duplicated lines (several lines per patient / pharmacy couple)